# JS-PHP. Uploadify return 500 error when file successfully uploaded on the server

Tags: php, jquery, kohana, uploadify

I'm using Kohana3 framework and Uploadify plugin for ajax file upload.

When I try to upload file Uploadify shows me 500 error. But if I check my download folder I can see that file uploaded successfully.

I've tried to send response via text or json or boolean, but there is no result.

What is a reason of this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following steps and check the uploading once again

1. Check the permission for the folder to which you are uploading the contents. ( Give full permission ie, 777 in linux )
2. Also check whether there's any apache configuration files/configurations ( .htaccess ) that block the url used to access/view the uploaded content

I think following these steps will solve your problem..

Comment: +1 almost certainly a permissions issue. More uncommonly, it could be a weird caching issue (just had a problem with this setting up a third party affiliate system)>